# is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have downloaded Laravel site in my Ubuntu (ru after that `composer update`) and I am getting this error, when try to access the site:

> is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

I see that the problem is in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php`, where the code is:

```
protected function loadViewsFrom($path, $namespace){

    if (is_array($this->app->config['view']['paths'])) {

        foreach ($this->app->config['view']['paths'] as $viewPath) {

            if (is_dir($appPath = $viewPath.'/vendor/'.$namespace)) {
                $this->app['view']->addNamespace($namespace, $appPath);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->app['view']->addNamespace($namespace, $path);
}
```

`$appPath` is string yes, but isn't it argument of type string for this function ?

If I put `var_dump()` right before is_dir check like this `var_dump($viewPath.'/vendor/'.$namespace);exit`, I am getting two paths:

> string(74) "/mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/project_folder/resources/views/vendor/notifications"
>
> string(71) "/mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/project_folder/resources/views/vendor/pagination"

These two folders in views folder doesn't exists. It doesn't matter, if I create them, but I think creating them is wrong. 
I can't understand where is the error.

It is same and if I:

```
   $appPath = $viewPath.'/vendor/'.$namespace;
   $cleaned = strval(str_replace("\0", "", $appPath));
   if (is_dir($cleaned)) {
       $this->app['view']->addNamespace($namespace, $appPath);
   }
```

Comment: Looks like you have three NUL bytes in both strings, from wherever.

Comment: This is not duplicate, because this is part of the Laravel installation, I CAN'T just edit that file, because it is not my custom code. Even, if I use the solution for anotoher question, there is still the same error.

Comment: Reopened, even though *not* solving the NUL byte issue isn't a very practical reason.

Comment: If I did the maths right, all your strings have exactly three more bytes than they should. You may want to `bin2hex()` them to find out which characters they are. It it possible they come from a file encoded as UTF-8 with BOM?